# Conditionally skipping a UIViewController in an iOS 5 app with UINavigatonController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

In our iOS application with three `UIViewController`s one after another, we would like to skip the middle one based on some condition and go directly from first to third. However, the user should be able to come back to the second one via the "Back" button on the third controller.

I tried `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueId" sender:sender];` from `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` but this corrupts the navigation bar as indicated by the debug log. Calling this code from `viewDidAppear` works fine, but then the second view is already displayed, which is what I was trying to avoid in the first place.

I also tried `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];` but the result is similarly corrupted nav bar, even though this time debug log does not have such entries.

What would be the supported way of doing this (if it is at all possible)?

The target is iPhone4 with iOS 5.1, and the dev environment is Xcode 4.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the following code in an app. Works exactly as expected.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        // skip second vc
        ThirdViewController *thirdVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThirdViewControllerViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:NO];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdVC animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        // push second vc
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. In order to be able to implement it this way, it looks like the controllers should not need any data from the previous one. Right now in our app each controller prepares the relevant data (based on user selection) for the subsequent controller during `prepareForSegue`. This is why I was looking for something that will allow me to "skip" (i.e. as if a segue is performed automatically). You gave me an idea to think about. Let me work on it and see if I can incorporate this idea into the app.

Comment: There was some shuffling involved but I got it working. I still wish there was somehow a way to "skip" (maybe via a segue or some other way) that would work within the same controller before the view appeared.

Comment: One detail I forgot to mention: The back button on the third controller after the skip is labeled "Back" rather than the title of the second controller as it would be under the normal sequence. Should this be set manually?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip a view controller you can just call `UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:`  It will animate to the last controller in the supplied array, and the user will be able to "back" out of that stack.

You can build up the array of view controllers any way you like; perhaps starting with the existing array of view controllers:

```
NSMutableArray* newViewControllers = [[navController.viewcontrollers mutablecopy] autorelease];

[newViewControllers addObject: ...];

[navController setViewControllers: newViewControllers animated: YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. This will be useful when there's a need to modify the stack deeply and/or in more complex situations. Right now pushing view controllers in sequence as suggested by another poster is working fine.