# How to unwind from UITabBarController to custom view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

I´ve a `UITabBarController` in the middle of a storyboard and I want that when I push ***back button*** on `UITabBarController` (TabBar) sends me to `View02` directly.

My sequence is:

> NavigationController->UIViewController01-> UIViewController02 -> UIViewController03 -> UITabBarController -> 3 TabBarViews

[image]
Could you help me, please?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditionally skipping a UIViewController in an iOS 5 app with UINavigatonController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692572/conditionally-skipping-a-uiviewcontroller-in-an-ios-5-app-with-uinavigatoncontro)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an unwind segue. First add a method in the view controller you want to unwind to:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToMyViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
{

}
```

Then in a view controller you want unwind from drag from the button to the green exit icon and select your action.

[image]

Comment: Thanks reecon, i want do this with back button of navigation bar no create a button....

Comment: @ADGP, Using the back button to do this is a bad idea. Users expect the back button to do one thing -- go back to the previous controller. That's the paradigm that Apple has set up, and to keep apps as intuitive as possible, it's best not to change the behavior of standard controls.